# Json encode in the Wrong Format

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I am trying to make some statistics over visits on my site. I know that I could use Google Analytics(which I do), but I want to try to do something myself and it is a good way to learn it.

**Problem:**
I select dates in my database and sort them to fit this week. After that, I want to add them to a json file. That json file are used by CanvasJS to make a Chart. I have tried some different ways, just to get it simi-working. But the format of the json array, is not the one CanvasJS want.

**What I need:**

```
{ visits:[[2019-02-12, 49,],[2019-02-13,40,],[2019-02-14,46,],[2019-02-15,37,], [2019-02-16,31,],[2019-02-17,38,],[2019-02-18,4,] }
```

**What I get:**

```
{ "visits":{"2019-02-12":49,"2019-02-13":40,"2019-02-14":46,"2019-02-15":37,"2019-02-16":31,"2019-02-17":38,"2019-02-18":4} }
```

**My PHP Script:**

```
// Get first and last day of the current week
$first_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- 6 days"));
$last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ 1 days "));

// Return all results the past 7 days
$sql = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '" . $first_day . "' AND date < '" . $last_day . "'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
    
    $response = array(); 
    $visits = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        
        $old_date = $row['date'];
        $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date_timestamp);
        
                // I don't need the keys, but I cant avoid it to
                // get it to work....
        $visits[] = array(
            'date' => $new_date
        );
        
    }
    
    // Add sum of Dates
    $response['visits'] = array_count_values(array_column($visits, 'date'));
    
    // Save to json File
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);
}
$conn->close();
```

Thanks to anyone able to help.

Comment: what you need is not valid json, dont count on php to provide for it with json_encode.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Can you point me in a direction or be a little more clear? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring any quote-related issues you might think are problems (but aren't), it seems your main difference is between what you want...

```js
[[2019-02-12, 49,],...
```

and what you have...

```js
{"2019-02-12":49,...
```

---

This is because [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-count-values.php) creates an associative array, with your dates as keys.

Your issue could be greatly simplified by getting your database to group and count instead of doing it in PHP. You can also benefit from using a prepared statement instead of direct value injection.

```php
// Get first and last day of the current week
$first_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("- 6 days"));
$last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+ 1 days "));

$sql = <<<_SQL
SELECT DATE(`date`), COUNT(1)
FROM `table` WHERE `date` BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
_SQL;

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $first_day, $last_day);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($date, $count);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $visits[] = [$date, $count];
}
$response = [ 'visits' => $visits ];

// Save to json File
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Could I get you to fit it into my code? I get both syntax errors in my editor and errors on the site, no matter how i implement it. (Errors are in the while visits[] and response = [...)

Comment: @lol25500 done. If you're still getting errors, please explain what they are in detail

Comment: Ah, you must be running a **very old** version of PHP (5.3 or older) if the short-array syntax is invalid

Comment: Should be version 7.1 - got the option to update to 7.3

Comment: @Phill Got something - visits: [ [ "2019-02-12 01:24:11", 1, ], [ "2019-02-12 01:28:44", 1, ], [ "2019-02-12 02:16:02", 1, ], [ "2019-02-12 02:37:50", 1, ], [ "2019-02-12 03:16:32", 1, ], [ "2019-02-12 04:05:28", 1, ], - but that is all request. I could just get everything out from DB by select.

I need it to match dates as before, count them and add to a new date that macthes the week day. Thats why I did it that strange way before :-)

Comment: I assumed your `date` fields were just that, _date_ fields and not _date-time_. You'll need to truncate the time-part. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to group same date as array inside visits, if I understand correctly here is a solution.

### Add one for more loop to make format php array before change it to json string.

```
$first_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 6 days'));
$last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 1 days '));

$sql = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '" . $first_day . "' AND date < '" . $last_day . "'";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    $response = [];
    $visits = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $old_date = $row['date'];
        $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date_timestamp);

        $visits[] = [
        'date' => $new_date
    ];
    }

    // here the change start
    $format = [];
    foreach ($visits as $visit) {
        $format[$visit['date']][] = $visit['date'];
    }
    $response['visits'] = array_values($format);
    // here the change end

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);
}
$conn->close();
```

### if you don't need the key `date` here another solution

```
$first_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('- 6 days'));
$last_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 1 days '));

$sql = "SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '" . $first_day . "' AND date < '" . $last_day . "'";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    $response = [];
    $visits = [];

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $old_date = $row['date'];
        $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
        $new_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date_timestamp);

        $visits[$new_date][] = $new_date; // change here
    }

    $response['visits'] = array_values($visits); // change here

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);
}
$conn->close();
```

### Explanation

in PHP there are two type of array indexed and associative, when you change PHP array to json string, indexed array goes to be array and associative goes to be object.

**example**

```
$indexed = [
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar'
];

$associative = [
    'one' => 'foo',
    'two' => 'bar'
];

var_dump(json_encode($indexed));
// [
//   "foo",
//   "bar"
// ]

var_dump(json_encode($associative));
// {
//   one: "foo",
//   two: "bar"
// }
```

in my code I use visit date as a key, that way the same date will goes into same array, and I `array_values` to convert associative to indexed